# Motion Sensor code use in class and call from main class

Tags: python, python-2.7, sensors, raspberry-pi3

**This is my motion sensor code**

```html
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)

pir = MotionSensor(4)

while True:
    if pir.motion_detected:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.HIGH)
        print("Motion detected!")
    
    else:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW)
```

**This is output**

```html
Motion detected!
Motion detected!
Motion detected!
```

**Help**
I want to use above code in the python class and access it from main python class.How to do it?Thank you!

**I Tried this**

**MainClass.py**

```html
import CalculateTime
import PeopleDetector
         
class Application:
      
           PeopleDetector.PIRDetection()
```

**PeopleDetector.py**

```html
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
    pir = MotionSensor(4)

    def PIRDetection():
        if pir.motion_detected:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.HIGH)
        print("Motion detected!")
        return 1;
    
        else:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW)
        return 0;
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/App/Python2/Main.py", line 2, in 
>       import PeopleDetector
>     File "/home/pi/App/Python2/PeopleDetector.py", line 5
>       GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
>       ^
>   IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: You should add the error in text, instead of image.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Dear Sir, I edited and add it.

Comment: The error you have is an indentation error. Just add an extra indent / tab after your if pir.motion_detected statement

Comment: Update the question with the new error.

Comment: it gives same error sir. this, "line 5 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent" @AshishNitinPatil

Comment: I think I code it wrong way. Can please tell correct way of doing this. I need to use my motion sensor code in a class and access its result from another class. @AshishNitinPatil Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python is a space-sensitive language. You need to use the correct indentation (tabs / 4-spaces consistently). The `if` & `else` declaratives require you to indent the code under them. The updated code you have does not contain the necessary tabs. Try this.

**PeopleDetector.py**

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
pir = MotionSensor(4)

def PIRDetection():
    if pir.motion_detected:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.HIGH)
        print("Motion detected!")
        return 1
    else:
        GPIO.output(3,GPIO.LOW)
        return 0
```

**MainClass.py**

```
import CalculateTime
import PeopleDetector

class Application:
    PeopleDetector.PIRDetection()
```

Comment: Did you use the exact code I have put up? Copy paste it, since you may miss the space / tabs.

Comment: It is working..Thank you very much sir! I'm very new to python.. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing need to know, how to put inside a class PeopleDetector.py code? and how to access it from MainClass.py. Can you please edit your code. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't understand what exactly you want. What code are you referring to?

Comment: I want to use def PIRDetection(): method inside a class (Like MainClass.py has class named Application)

Comment: Its ok sir. I did it. Thank you!